# VsCode with ReactJS: Is it possible to auto complete double quotes when emmeting "className"?

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio-code

Using VSCode with ReactJS, I have the following JSX:

```
class BookList extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className></div>
    );
  }
}
```

Is it possible to auto complete double quotes after I emmet `className` so that I don't have to do it everytime and for the cursor to be placed between both quotes?

```
<div className=""></div>
```

Comment: Did you find its solution.

Comment: I'm pretty sure VSCode does this for you now if you type `className` and then tab.

Comment: Tab did not work for me. I wrote user snippet to achieve this.